# Selecting from three tables, distinct selections from one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, I'll call them table A, B and C here. Table A has a one to many relation to B and B has a one to many relation with C. For this query, I only want disctinct values from C, but the query below will give me multpile C records that match B.

Right now my query is as such:

```
Select * from A Left Outer Join B on A.key = B.key Left Outer Join C on B.AltKey = C.AltKey
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for A, B and C and identify which row(s) you actually want? Also please specify which version of SQL Server you are using. The solution might be quite different for SQL Server 2000 vs. SQL Server 2008, for example.

Comment: Hey Aaron, I'm using MSSQL 2008. I provided a detailed description of what I'm trying to see in my comment to AJ. Think of table A as projects, B as audits, and C as Findings. So it would look something like this:Project0 null null, Project1 Audit1 Finding1, Project2 Audit2 null, Project2 Audit3 Finding3, Project 2 Audit 4 null, etc..    So, for example, I would not want Project2 Audit3 Finding4 to show as a record.

Comment: Still think it would be useful to see . It's tough to determine the true relational aspect of statements like "only one per match, hence the desire for distinct" and "I only want to show one record" - if there are 5 rows in C, you need to tell SQL Server which one you want. If you just want to know that there is at least one row in C, then it may be solved a different way (an EXISTS subquery instead of a join, for example). So, sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: I'm joining C on B where C.altkey = B.altkey. There may be several C tuples with a altkey that is equal to the altkey of one B tuple. I don't need multiple tuples showing, only to know that a C tuple maps to a B tuple. So I'm thinking an exist query may hold promise. : )

Comment: Ok. Once again, can you show sample data (including all edge cases, e.g. one row in B & C, multiple rows in B & C, no rows in B & C, row in B & not in C) and desired results from that data. Not in a comment, but in some kind of tabular form in the question. (My previous comment should have said "Still think it would be useful to see sample data and desired results.")

Comment: The more I thought about this, the more I think it may be impractical/impossible to do. I would give you data but it is proprietary and I gave an example of what I want in my first comment to you. I was running user defined queries based on what columns they wanted to see. I was using a date filter for a column that was in table C, but if the user decided they only wanted to see columns from A and B, then I was thinking how I would display the results. I decided to just display a message saying they need to select a column from table C if they want to query using that date filter function.

Comment: I should add that the filter for column C was in a combo box and could be switched to a filter for column B before you think I'm too crazy.:P I know this seems kind of vague, but it's kind of hard to describe the scope of this project in comments. Thanks for your quick help though!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using LEFT OUTER JOIN?  Try switching that with plain old JOIN and see if you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Im using left outer join because I want to see all records in A regardless of whether they have matches in B and All records from B regardless of whether they have matches in C. But I don't want to see multiple records of C's matching to B's, only one per match, hence the desire for distinct. I.E. there are 5 rows in C that have a key value that matches the key of a record in B, but I only want to show one record, not five. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct C.* from C
Left Outer Join B on C.a = B.a 
Left Outer Join A on B.a = A.a
```

Comment: He wants all records of A regardless of if a B exists for it. And a B must exist for a C to be linked to it. So he would not get all A's with this query.

Comment: But I want to see columns that are in B and A. This will only show me columns from table C, correct?

Comment: Yes, distinct + only from C. In your query you mentioned that you want from C distinct

Comment: Hmm, since I need columns from A and B, that is not quite what I want, but thanks for the input!

Comment: You want distinct values from A and B ? or you want distinct values C ?

Comment: If you only want distinct of C values, please check my answer. Let me know in case of any issues

Comment: Again, I want columns that are in A and B, this would only give columns from C.